# Marker on menu-item with sub-items

Tags: php, wordpress, nav

I really love that Wordpress makes my menu automatically, and that i do not need to use the Apperance->Menus system if i do not want to. Child pages can be styled as dropdowns and everything is good.

Except: I can't manage to make a marker on top level menu-items, to show that there are sub-items present. How can i do this, without using the Apperance->Menus system?

Menu is created with:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Anders

Comment: try [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/hierarchical-pages/)

Answer (score 0):

you can apply some marker background/css to only first child/li of ul. You can use JQuery as following. It should only apply to first level li of your primary menu.

```
$("ul.menu > li").css('background-image', 'url(images/marker.png)');
```